# Convert Jersey 1.x client to Jersey 2.x client

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I have the following code which works with jersey 1.x. However, I need to make it work with jersey 2.x and I noticed that a lot of the jersey classes and methods changed from one version to another. Any idea?

```
Client client = null;

try {
    URLConnectionClientHandler ch = new URLConnectionClientHandler(new ProxyConnectionFactory(proxyHost, proxyPort));
    client = new Client(ch);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
    ClientResponse response = ((Builder) webResource.type("application/json").header(authKey, authCreds)).post(ClientResponse.class, input);
    
    String output = (String) response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);
    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        System.out.println("Status Failed, Status: " + response.getStatus());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
        //additional code
    }
    
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception occurred");
} finally {
    client.destroy();
}
```

In this code snippet, ProxyConnectionFactory is a class which sets the proxy configuration. It implements HttpURLConnectionFactory which is also a jersey 1.x interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic type analogs would be as follows:

| Jersey 1.x | Jersey 2.x |
| --- | --- |
| `Client` | [`javax.ws.rs.client.Client`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) |
| `WebResource` | [`javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) |
| `ClientResponse` | [`javax.ws.rs.core.Response`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) |

To build the client, you generally use one of the [`ClientBuilder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) static builder methods. The most basic one to use would be the `newClient()` method, which returns a new instance of the `Client`

```java
Client client = ClientBuider.newClient();
```

If you need to configure the client, you can do so in multiple ways. For instance, if you need to register some properties or providers, you can:

- Configure while building:

  ```
  Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
          .property("...", "...")
          .register(SomeProvider.class)
          .build();
  ```
- Use a [`ClientConfig`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientConfig.html):

  ```
  ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig()
          .property("...", "...")
          .register(SomeProvider.class);
  Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
  ```
- Configure the client directly

  ```
  Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
  client.property("...", "...");
  client.register(SomeProvider.class);
  ```

Once you have a `Client`, you want to get a `WebTarget`. You would do that by providing a URI to the `Client#target()` method.

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
```

If you need to do anything to the URI like add a path, query param, or matrix param, you would do so on the `WebTarget`. Otherwise you would now call the `WebTarget#request()` method to get an [`Invocation.Builder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html)

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
Invocation.Builder invBuilder = target.request();
```

With the `Invocation.Builder`, you can add headers and finally make the request. You don't have to assign any new variable to the `Invocation.Builder` (or even the `WebTarget` for that matter). I did so for demonstrative purposes. You can continue to chain the method calls. For example

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.target(url)
        .request()
        .header(authHey, authCreds)
```

Finally to make the request, you would use one of the HTTP methods of the `Invocation.Builder`. In your case it would be the `post()` method. You can pass an [`Entity`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html) to this method and the result would be a `Response`

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response res = client.target(url)
        .request()
        .header(authHey, authCreds)
        .post(Entity.json(input));
```

To read the response, you use `Response#readEntity(Class)`

```java
String data = res.readEntity(String.class);
```

If you have a POJO class you want the response to be deserialized to then pass that class to the `readEntity()` method. You will need to have a provider for whatever data type is expected. For example if it is JSON to be converted to a POJO, then you'll want to have the Jackson provider:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Proxies

As far as the proxy goes, Jersey has some properties you can set

- [`ClientProperties.PROXI_URI`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.html#PROXY_URI)

  ```
  Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient()
          .property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, String.format("%s:%s", host, port));
  ```

#### See also

- For full documentation on the Jersey 2.x client, see [the docs](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. After adding the following imports:
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

I tried creating a client with Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(); However, I get an error executing that call. Here is the exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/UnsafeValue
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3296)

Comment: Make sure _all_ your Jersey dependency versions are the _same_

Comment: This was due to missing dependencies. I am now able to create the client. However, getting a timeout on  Response res = client.target(url).request().header(authKey, authCreds).post(Entity.json(input));  - Can input be a String in this case?

Comment: Yes it can. If you are getting a timeout there might be problem with the server.

Comment: You'll get a timeout when there's a problem with the connection. It be a problem with either the proxy or the server.

Comment: @MandyLastra what was that missing dependency ?